# Gibb's energy change for system

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

> Heat liberated by a given amount of an ideal gas is $\pu{1200 cal}$ at $\pu{300K}$. What is the Gibbs free energy change for the gas in this process?

**My attempt:** I know that for a reversible process the net Gibbs energy change of the system + surrounding will be zero. But I have no idea how to calculate the Gibbs energy change of the system alone. The only equation I know involving Gibbs energy is $ΔG=ΔH-TΔS$, but this equation will give me the net Gibbs energy change and not the change in free energy of the system alone.

Comment: Is that the exact verbatim statement of the question?

Comment: Well, if it happens at constant temperature, $\Delta H=0$ and $T\Delta S=Q=-1200$.